# Testing whether a sample of correlated R.V are $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

Suppose I have a sample $X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n$.

I do not assume these are independent, in fact I suspect they are slightly correlated, however I do suspect that the marginal distribution of each individually is identical and $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

How does one go about testing whether they are indeed identically distributed?

Since I don't have a random sample, the tests I'm used to using can't be applied. I am pretty sure I can come up with some permutation tests to test different aspects of this, but is there a way to test $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ specifically?

---

**Edit:** My current approach is to thin the data so I only take every $n$th value. Then the correlation is negligible (it's time series data) and I can treat it as a random sample. However, this causes me to lose a lot of information so I'd really like a better approach.

Comment: Wouldn't you need multiple copies of the n tuple $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, ..., $X_n$ to estimate each mean and variance and compare to see if they are the same? You would also need these copies to determine whether each $X_i$ is normally distributed.

Comment: Assuming I have estimates for $\mu, \sigma^2$ already I mean, which I believe are the marginal distribution parameters for each $X_i$, how would I test it with just one sample? If that makes sense. If I am talking nonsense then please let me know lol.

Comment: I think that if you presuppose that you have a single estimate for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ to use you are already assuming that the $X_i$s all have the same mean and variance.  It seems to me that you need more data to verify this as well as to test the normality assumption.